# Running Eclipse Che behind Apache2 reverse proxy?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, eclipse-che

Currently, I have eclipse che installed running on port localhost:8080 and I have this virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    ServerName example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

This lets me access the eclipse che however I can't load any workspaces I just get a flashing eclipse che logo and nothing happens.

How do I resolve this?

Also how would I implement a login system so that I can add some sort of authentication to eclipse che?